# (do while) measuring until the value doesnt change anymore

Tags: c, do-while

I'm trying to measure a value and use it, when it is stable. I thought I could use a do while loop and use a second value to compare it with the main value. Here is my code:

```
          do {
            mess.Acal[mess.j][0] = analoginput();
            HAL_Delay(100);
            mess.x2 = analoginput();
          } while (mess.x2 - mess.Acal[mess.j][0] >= 0.000001 && mess.Acal[mess.j][0] -mess.x2 >=0.000001 );
                                                                                                                                                
    }
```

x2 and Acal are both doubles.
So basically I measure the first value (e.g 1.256301222V). Then with HAL_delay, i let the program wait 100ms and redo the measurement on x2 (e.g 1.256268049V). For the while i thought i can subtrahate both and it breaks out if the difference is under 0.000001V. Somehow the loop breaks, even though the Difference is: 0.000033182V, which is > 0.000001V. Is it not possible to subtrahate such small values? Or does while() not work like this?
Thanks for the help.

Comment: I think you want `||`, not `&&` there.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError x2 could be smaller then Acal, if this occured it could happen: x2-Acal= -0.01....  which is smaller than +0.000001. Thats why i && the opposite.

Comment: @MarcHammer: Here's how I'd express the desired logic in plain speak: continue while the delta between the two measurements is too great on the positive side OR too great on the negative side.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError Hmm i will try it. But isn't OR just checking the first condition and if it is false it goes to the second? Because I think OR will just read the delta between the negative two measurements, because this condition is true it will directly break out of the loop.

Comment: No, for `||`, if the first condition is false, the second will be evaluated. The expression as a whole must evaluate to `true` if either of the sides does. So it's the opposite, actually, if the first evaluates to true the second does not need to be evaluated.

Comment: Of course you could side-step this whole issue by doing `while (fabs(mess.x2 - mess.Acal[mess.j][0]) >= 0.000001);` - cleaner, IMHO.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError
Thank you, now it is working! I didn't understand the OR Operation correctly.

Comment: Do you actually have a 32 bit resolution sensor though? You work at NASA or something? If you don't have 32 bit resolution in hardware, then you don't have this problem you describe either.

Comment: @Lundin no i don't work at Nasa :D Actually i have no Information about the resolution of the sensor ( at least not in V). My ADC has a 24Bit resolution.

Comment: @MarcHammer Then everything beyond 24 bit is noise that you can and should disregard. 24 bit delta sigma is very high tech too, you need a very specialized board design to actually utilize that.